# Change in Free Energy on Approach to Equilibrium in a System with Fixed Volume

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a system whose volume and particle number are fixed. The system starts out at temperature $T_0$ and is then put in thermal contact with a reservoir at temperature $T_r \neq T_0$. It is often said that the free energy $F := E - TS$ of the system decreases to a minimum as it comes to thermal equilibrium with the reservoir. But
$$\begin{split}dF = d(E-TS) &= dE - TdS-SdT \\ &= (TdS-PdV)-TdS-SdT \\ &=-SdT \end{split}$$
since the system's volume is fixed. If $T_0 > T_r$, the system's temperature will decrease as it approaches thermal equilibrium with the reservoir, so $dT < 0$ and $dF > 0$. What's wrong with this argument? Note that the thermodynamic identity $dE = TdS - PdV$ that I used in the second line holds even for irreversible processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimization of the Helmholtz free energy requires the system to be under constant $(T,V,N)$.  In the example you have given the temperature is not constant, therefore we cannot use the minimization of the Helmholtz free energy to obtain the equilibrium state.

Answer (score 3):

The equation does not apply at every point along an irreversible process path.  It only applies to the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states, and then only if these two end states are very close to one another.

Comment: That's true, the system doesn't have an equilibrium state throughout the process (only at the endpoints), so I can't make any statements about the change in free energy $dF$ for a small part of the process. But we can construct a reversible path that has the same endpoints, and along this path $dF = -SdT$ is valid. Moreover, since $S := -k\sum_{i}{p_i\ln{p_i}}$ is always positive (except in the case when $p_i$ is zero for all but one microstate-- then $S = 0$), integrating $dF$ along the reversible path gives us a positive change in the free energy if $T_0 > T_r$.

Comment: I challenge you to define such a reversible path using a single reservoir at Tr < To.

Comment: I don't see any reason that we have to use a single reservoir. We can use a series of reservoirs with temperatures changing gradually between $T_0$ and $T_r$ to  construct a reversible path from the system's initial state to its final state. As long as the endpoints are the same, the change in the system's free energy along this reversible path will be the same as the actual change in its free energy.

Comment: You said in your OP there is a single reservoir.

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about two different processes. In one, the actual process, the system's temperature changes irreversibly from $T_0$ to $T_r$. In the other, the system is transformed reversibly, with the same initial and final states as in the actual process. This is accomplished by connecting the system to reservoirs with temperature gradually changing from $T_0$ to $T_r$. Since free energy is a function of state, the change in the system's free energy is the same for this hypothetical process as for the actual process.